# Constant Integer and Array Initialization in C

Tags: c, arrays, constants

I have this expression:

```
const int numPlayers = 2;
player players[numPlayers];
```

This is an array of user-defined type players (using struct). However, I get an error saying that `numPlayers` has to be a constant value.

```
expression must have a constant value
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

I have also initialized the array like this:

```
player *players = (player*)calloc(sizeof(player), numPlayers);
```

But I cannot access any of the local variables of the struct without the program crashing.

Comment: `#define numPlayers 2`, declaring an `int` as `const` is not a constant for purposes of array declaration.

Comment: Also, you have the arguments to [`calloc(size_t num, size_t size)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) backwards.

Comment: seems ancient version of C. Works weell in modern compilers. BTW #define style `is medicine worse than the disease`

Comment: [don't cast the result of the `malloc` family in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C99, the below works fine inside a function.  It is a *variable length array* (VLA).

```
const int numPlayers = 2;
player players[numPlayers];
```

Otherwise use a `#define` for a true *constant*.

```
#define numPlayers 2
player players[numPlayers];
```

Answer (score 0):

`const` are not true constants, the compiler will not allow you to change the value only. I will suggest use `#define numPlayers 2` instead.